# Indexing to to elasticsearch has strange behavior with unexpected result

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-pig

I am using apache pig to index some documents to elasticsearch but when I do all of the emails are look like a hashed string of characters. Ex.

```
    "_index": "es_test",
    "_type": "base",
    "_id": "AVGCeBXUxBi_sF1H5RcL",
    "_source": {
      "Email": "UmF3QHNoYXcuY2E=",
```

This is my pig script so far

```
REGISTER /home/PigDump/elasticsearch-hadoop-2.1.1.jar;
DEFINE EsStorage org.elasticsearch.hadoop.pig.EsStorage('es.nodes=http://10.0.2.2:9200');
Customer = LOAD '/home/PigOut/Base.json/part-r-00000' USING JsonLoader();
STORE Customer INTO 'es_test/base' USING EsStorage;
```

All other fields look fine. Does anybody know why the emails are getting messed up?

When I do a `DUMP` this is an example of the output:

```
(foobar@email.com,2008-05-14T01:32:00.000Z,60+,garden city,john Smith,remodeling,id,n,po box 555555,,some company, llc,usa,,555-555-5555,123-123-5555,83714,,002,160,100,159,,,,,,1)
```

I changed some of the data to protect identity but you get the gist and the multiple commas are from some fields being null.

And to make things more confusing I am able to set the id as the email using `es.mapping.id=Email` and this works fine and the email is not hashed.

Comment: I didn't experience anything like this. Are you sure that your input data is correct? Did you tried to dump a part of it just to double-check? Can you share some example of the input data?

Comment: Yes, I tried that and all of the data looks fine. Its like the email gets hashed when it gets indexed and I'm so confused as to why.

Comment: Could it be something messed up in my schema?

Comment: Is your loaded data schema is correct? You createdthe ES mapping or let it do for you based on the schema? I did a trial where I loaded email addresses from a file with pig storage and stored them into ES an it worked fine. Mapping created by ES {"so":{"mappings":{"emails":{"properties":{"email":{"type":"string"}}}}}} and the data {"took":2,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":1,"max_score":0.2712221,"hits":[{"_index":"so","_type":"emails","_id":"AVGDiDm9uUfhvLVkWAMS","_score":0.2712221,"_source":{"email":"abc@yahoo.com"}}]}} the email is just fine.

Comment: My schema has email as a byte array and I need it to be in a char array. I'm trying to figure out how to cast it now.

Answer (score 0):

So the answer lies in the schema file that pig generates with the data I was using. In the schema file the type for email was 50 which is a byte array. When I changed it to 55, a char array, the indexing works fine. So what looked like hashed values were actually just bytes. I will add a follow up question of what the schema types are for fields and link it later.

Comment: Yes I'm expected something like that, I'm glad you figured it out and hope I also helped a bit :)